# Does silicon have catenation property?

Tags: hydrocarbons

We know that there are countless organic compounds of carbon chain because of carbon's catenation. Silicon also is in the same group of carbon. Does it also have the catenation property? If not, why?

Comment: Somewhat related question with useful answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47432/544

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/what-makes-carbon-special-and-versatile